# Visualizing Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, visualization

I have encountered a bit a of problem when visualizing linear maps, a colleague of mine seems to have no problem and can tell purely by the matrix in question what the transformed space will look like even in $3D$.

I just cant seem to do it even when using a visualization tool often the image in my head seems to be wrong in some respects.

I have taken vector calculus and never had a problem visualizing things in $3D$ any suggestions of how i can rectify this problem?

Comment: Can he/she do four (or more) dimensions?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No just $3$ but pretty quickly she is a programmer

Comment: You might find [this video to be helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE), and also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHLEWRxRGiM) from the same author on the 3-dimensional case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i have seen them already sorry to disappoint you

Comment: @AtifFarooq hmm, well can you be more specific then?  What kinds of things should you be able to tell about the transformation which you're finding difficult?  Maybe you have some kind of example?